# Special characters from SQL Server Linked Server to IBM DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, linked-server, db2-luw

I'm having a bad issue with the following topic: I'm trying to migrate some data from a SQL Server database to an IBM DB2 database (LUW v11.1) . For this purpose, I'm using a linked server using DB2OLEDB driver.

So, when I execute the following statement

```
insert into [MyDB].[MyDB76].[SCHEMA].TABLE (DESCRIPTION, ID)
SELECT N'a', ID FROM VW_TABLE
where TABLEID=35
```

all works fine, but if I insert a special characters, replacing **"a" with "à"**

```
insert into [MyDB].[MyDB76].[SCHEMA].TABLE (DESCRIPTION, ID)
SELECT N'à', ID FROM   VW_TABLE
where TABLEID=35
```

the following error message occurs

> OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "MyDB" returned message "An internal network library error has occurred. A network level syntax error has occurred. SQLSTATE: HY000, SQLCODE: -379".
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
> The OLE DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server "MyDB" could not INSERT INTO table "[MyDB].[MyDB76].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]".

I tried to "play" with linked server configuration parameters (see below please) but I haven't success.

[image: 1]

Does anybody know any tricks to solve this issue?

Many thanks

Comment: The sqlcode -379 state 2, indicates that a distributed transaction had a commit failure, and the real reason will be in the Db2 diagnostics.  You need to talk with the Db2 DBA to see what is in the Db2 diagnostics.  You should specify in your question which __platform__ of Db2-server (z/os , i series, linux/unix/windows/cloud/zlinux).  Also, it's unclear why you have enabled Distributed Transaction in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using DB2 LUW v11.1)

Comment: What's in the Db2 diagnostics when the -379 sqlcode happens?

Comment: how you created this link server, i am trying create this using "IBM DB2 ODBC Driver - DB2COPY1" this driver but its showing error?

Comment: what is the schema of that table in db2 ?

Comment: I suspect that the source tbale is not set for unicode data?

Comment: The source table has all the fields nvarchar(max) so Unicode is set. Moreover, driver works well i.e. withous errors. In fact, I can insert record without special characters in fields as I described

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it form sql server?

something like:

```
insert into openquery (DB2server, select col1, col2, col3 from your_table)

select col1, col2, replace(col3,'a','à') from your_sqlserver_table
```

Comment: I don't want replace characters. The 'à' is, in fact, an example. I have other special characters in my record and I can't replace all of them.